# How to put plots without any space using plot_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid, cowplot

I'm doing an arrangement of 2x2 plots. The plots share the same axis, so I want to put them together, e.g.

This code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

Value <- seq(0,1000, by = 1000/10)
Index <- 0:10
DF <- data.frame(Index, Value)


plot <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(linetype = 2) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.5)

plot_grid(plot, plot, plot, plot, align = "hv", ncol = 2)
```

produces

[image]

But I'd like something like:

[image]

How can I achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a case for the `ggarrange()` function from the `egg` package. Doing this with `plot_grid()` would require endless fiddling and isn't worth it.

(The technical reason is that `plot_grid()` keeps the total area for each plot in the grid constant, but if some plots have an x axis and others don’t then they take up different areas. One could try to circumvent this by using the `rel_heights` argument but there’s no good way to calculate the correct values for `rel_heights`, so it would be trial and error. By contrast, `ggarrange()` separately looks at the plot panel and the surrounding elements and makes sure the plot panels have the same size.)

Here is the code using `ggarrange()`:

```
Value <- seq(0,1000, by = 1000/10)
Index <- 0:10
DF <- data.frame(Index, Value)


pbase <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(linetype = 2) +
  theme_bw()

ptopleft <- pbase +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(5.5, 0, 0, 5.5),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())

ptopright <- pbase +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 0, 0),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())

pbottomleft <- pbase +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 5.5, 5.5))

pbottomright <- pbase +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 5.5, 5.5, 0))

library(egg)      
ggarrange(ptopleft, ptopright,
          pbottomleft, pbottomright,
          ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Two comments:

1. To remove every last bit of space below the plot panel on the top plots, we need to move the x axis to the top, even though we're not showing it. This is a strange limitation of the theming mechanism. We can't fully get rid of just one axis.
2. I'm not a big fan of shared axis titles, as in your example. I think each axis should have a title. If you want shared axis titles, why not use the faceting mechanism?

Comment: This is great! Sometimes people have different plot types, perhaps different data sources and types, which won't work with faceting.

Answer (score 4):

You can set subtle `plot.margin` each plot, then `grid.arrange` and add labs.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

Value <- seq(0,1000, by = 1000/10)
Index <- 0:10
DF <- data.frame(Index, Value)

plot1 <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(linetype = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.5, 
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(5.5, 5.8, -50, 5.5), "pt")) 

plot2 <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(linetype = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.5, 
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(5.5, 5.5, -50, 5.5), "pt")) +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right")

plot3 <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(linetype = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.5, 
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(-50, 5.8, -50, 5.5), "pt")) 

plot4 <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(linetype = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.5, 
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(-50, 5.5, -50, 5.5), "pt")) +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right")

grid.arrange(grobs = list(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4), ncol = 2, bottom = 'Index', left = 'Value', right = 'Value')
```

final plot
[image]